# Get number of checkboxes that are checked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, forms

I am trying to make a javascript function (although jquery is perfectly OK) that will return a number that corresponds to the number of checkboxes checked in a form.  Seems simple enough but I can't figure out a good way of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
var formobj = document.forms[0];

var counter = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < formobj.elements.length; j++)
{
    if (formobj.elements[j].type == "checkbox")
    {
        if (formobj.elements[j].checked)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }       
}

alert('Total Checked = ' + counter);
```

.

**With JQuery:**

```
alert($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').size());
```

Comment: Just for clarification - the standard JS code will not pick up input elements that are not inside a form. The jQuery line will.

Comment: @danp: yes now both ways will select all checkboxes from a form.

Comment: With the JQuery, like $('form input[type=checkbox]:checked'), how to get the details about the id of item that is checked?

Answer (score 4):

`$('form :checkbox:checked').length`

Comment: Whats the difference between .length and .size()?

Comment: @Mint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute

Answer (score 4):

```
 var checkBoxs = $('#myForm').children('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
 alert(checkBoxs.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var chk = $('form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(":checkbox").filter(":checked").size()
```

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: Just for illustration. I have now removed it
@Sarfraz: You are right. I've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

vary long way

you have to give the class name to checkbox and do

var chkLength = $('input.className:checked').length;

alert(chkLength);

this will gove all checked checkBoxes from list of checkbox