# jQuery size() method vs length attribute

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between `$(".selector").size()` and `$(".selector").length`  ?

Comment: From the code: `size: function() { return this.length; }` :P

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) is [**deprecated**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10657) in favor of [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), because `.length` has slightly better performance.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No. `size()` returns `length`. By using `length` you only avoid one extra method call.

Comment: Be aware that `.size()` is now (as of 1.8) deprecated and `.length` is indicated in the docs as the appropriate approach. See https://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 16):

Length returns the same thing and is slightly faster according to the jQuery documentation.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 9):

They will both give you the same result but .length is slightly faster.

See http://api.jquery.com/size/:

> The .length property is a slightly faster way to get this information.

Answer (score 7):

Length is much faster.

See the tutorial [size vs. length](http://jsperf.com/size-vs-length).

Comment: I would not call a < 0.5% runtime difference much faster (http://jsperf.com/size-vs-length) but there is some overhead associated with the function call.

Answer (score 3):

.size() is a Method call, which returns the length property. So you either call the method to return the property, or you retrieve the property directly.

The method (.size()) is probably the one you should be using, as it was most likely implemented to abstract away from the possibility of the length property being changed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! There is now a very significant difference. [`.size()` is deprecated.](http://api.jquery.com/size/) Always use `.length` instead.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery **size()** is a method & **length** is property and property is faster than method because **size()** internally calls length. so better to call length directly.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .size() and .length both return the number of elements in the jQuery object.

Size() and length in jQuery both returns the number of element in an object but length is faster than the size because length is a property and size is a method and length property does not have the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Well that's the same answer like the accepted answer which was given 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you will read `length` property then only time required to access an object property will be needed.

However if you will call `size()` then first of all a function will be called, this function will read `length` property internally and then return that value to the caller.

You can clearly see that you are doing the same thing in both cases. But if you call the function then it will include time for calling a function + returning that value too..

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay. However, length is better being a property than size() which is a method.

Moreso size() has been deprecated from jquery 1.8 and removed as of version 3.1.

So use length as much as possible