# Why jquery defined two methods for the same purpose? size and length

Tags: jquery

After reading [this SE Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute) a question pops up. Why jquery defined two methods for the same purpose? Is there any purpose I missed?

Don't know this belongs to a wiki discussion. If so please guide me to change this so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess someone just didn't think it through, <s>unless perhaps the earliest versions had some reason. I could only find source back to `1.2.6`, and it is unchanged from the current version</s>.

**EDIT:** *It seems to have been unchanged since version 1.0.1.*

The [documentation for `.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) suggests that it should not be used.

> You should use the .length property instead, which is slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. If we think it is confusing, should we raise bug/correction request in jquery official forum/bug tracking system? Or need more research?

Comment: @rajakvk - The best you could probably hope for would be some additional clarification in the documentation. I would doubt it will be removed from the API at this point, though. If I as to guess, I'd say that the request would be marked as "invalid" or perhaps "low priority" at best. Couldn't hurt to try though. :o)

Answer (score 1):

length is a property inherit from javascript

size() is a method

Answer (score 0):

size returns length. Length is a bit faster.

Comment: Length is faster because its a core javascript method , isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

["most likely implemented to abstract away from the possibility of the length property being changed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute/2738395#2738395)

Comment: oh... Is there any proposal to change length property in near future?

Comment: don't know ... I'm quoting someone else's answer as it seems the most reasonable explanation of the design decision