# how to check whether the span element present or not

Tags: jquery

I want to know the method to check if there is span element present or not..
if so that element should remove and add new span element...
if there is no span element, then add the span element now...
not only for span tell me the method which is applicable to all the situations or elements

Thank you

Comment: sorry.. small mistake.. if there is already span element that should remove and add a new span element..

Answer (score 5):

`if($('#id').length)` // tells you whether it exists or not

based on you can write your logic

```
if ($('#my-element').length) {
     // #my-element exists
}

use jquery's .remove()//or .hide()
```

Comment: "best practice" from jquery -- use .size() method to determine what number of elements is in jquery-object, not .length property

Comment: @genius .size and length are almost doesn't the same thing right?? can you tell me what is the siginificat difference , i think even with performance , lenght is better to check if that element exists or not

Comment: @genius do you have any link which says size is better than length , please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute , length is faster than size, size inturn does a return length

Comment: @gov, hm.. you are right. probably they changed their mind. now i see on official jquery page: "You should use the .length property instead, which is slightly faster.". formerly they strongly recommended to use size()

Comment: @genius doesn't matter too much anyway , the tradeoff is very minimal , we can use whatever you remember while coding any way nice discussion , its always good to learn new things, i learnt about size from you todya , thanks...

Comment: @gov, no, thank you! I just spent some time to investigate what a difference in these methods (in time), and .length is really faster. *Went away to replace all .size() to .length in slow codes*