# How do I use jQuery selectors to affect different siblings of the same class?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get Length to count the number of images in a series of divs that have the same class name, but I can't get jQuery to see each DIV individually.

```
console.log($('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
        console.log($('.channel_titles_art img').length);
      })
);
```

For example, I'd like it to output: div one: 4 images, div two: 2 images, div three: 12 images...

but instead it counts the total number of images that are children of all the divs using the channel_titles_art class and repeats the number that many times (for three divs "18 images" repeats three times)

Is there a way to iterate through each div separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to use `this`:

```
$('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
    console.log($('img', this).length);
})
```

to display what you want:

```
$('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
    var amt_of_images = $('img', this).length;
    console.log(this, 'has '+amt_of_images+' images');
})
```

here is the [fiddle :-)](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/SjaW6/)

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been banging my head against the table on this one for a while.

Comment: Just for laughs: `$(this).find('img')` might be ever so slightly faster than `$('img', this)` because the latter is implemented using the former. This will lead to more function calls if the latter is used. Once again - do what ever is clearest if there isn't real need for micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Convert the `$('.channel_titles_art img')` to `$('img', this)` or `$(this).find('img')`.

These will find all image that are within the context of the current element that matches `.channel_titles_art` while the original matcher matched all images within all `.channel_titles_art`.

Examples with find (copy-paste from [Neal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal)) with `.size()` instead of `.length` to show alternatives.

```
$('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
    console.log($(this).find('img').size());
})
```

And

```
$('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
    var amt_of_images = $(this).find('img').size();
    console.log(this, 'has '+amt_of_images+' images');
})
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjaW6/2/) (again abusing the good work of Neal).

Comment: this is incorrect. how would the OP do that? `$(this).('img')` is incorrect jQuery

Comment: Absolutely correct, checked and fixed. Thank you! I always seem to forget to add the find.

Comment: also `.length` is faster, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738352/jquery-size-method-vs-length-attribute

Comment: @Neal I hope I gave you proper credit. If not I'm willing to modify the answer according to make you feel less slighted. My goal is to keep enhancing my answer until it's good and complete enough. The different variations have been added before consulting the other answers. I have reused your code as I think it is more beneficial to the OP to see only the small difference between solutions instead of having to plow through various changes that are irrelevant. I do think that you are the one who should get the respect and accepted answer to this one and I hope my answer just completes it a bit

Comment: @Neal great link once again. I was hoping to give an alternative with a more jqueryish feel by using `.size()` instead of `.length`. In most cases the performance penalty is negligible and one should concentrate on which ever seems to provide more clarity in their own experience.

Answer (score 2):

Yup. You're asking it for every single element with a class of `channel_titles_art`, and then asking for all the images within *all* of those within the `each` block. You need to specify. You can use `this` as a reference to the current item you're working with, and then use the `parent` field of the `$` function to specify to work from that.

```
console.log($('.channel_titles_art').each( function(){
        console.log($('img', this).length);
      })
);
```