# Checked inputs length

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get number of checkboxes that are checked in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697329/get-number-of-checkboxes-that-are-checked-in-javascript)

```
obj = document.getElementById('myform').elements.length.checked;
```

Is this the wrong code if I want to check the number of checked inputs?

Comment: *"Is this the wrong code if I want to check the number of checked inputs?"*: Yes.

Comment: *"Is this the wrong code if I want to check the number of checked inputs?"* - Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will set obj to undefined as length is a number which doesn't have a property `checked`. Try something like this

```
var el = document.getElementById('myform').elements;
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++)
{
    if(el[i].type == "checkbox" && el[i].checked)
    {
        count++
    }
}

alert(count);
```

Comment: `length` is a number. But in any way, the code won't throw an error. `checked` is just a property which is not defined, so `obj` will be `undefined`.

Comment: +1 This is actually more effective since you only store a number in memory.

Comment: @Daniel: Try to understand the code and you will find out. There are only three variables.

Comment: thanks a lot dear friend. You're so kind. Sorry my newbieness :P

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate over all elements and filter the checked ones out: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Yfpt3/.

```
var form = document.getElemen tById('form'); // the form
var elements = form.elements;                // the form's elements
var checked = [];                            // we will fill this with checked elements

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {   // iterate over all elements
    if(elements[i].checked) {                // if this one is checked
        checked.push(elements[i]);           // add to the checked elements array
    }
}

alert(checked.length);                       // alert amount of checked elements
```

Comment: Thanks friend... it helped a lottttt...