# Validation of multiple checkbox and implode function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, validation

The below is a snippet

```
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Tick the Teaching Methods Used </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="lectures" name="lectures" value="lectures">Lectures &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="study" name="study" value="study">Case Study &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="audvid" name="audvid" value="audvid">Audio|Video &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="interactive" name="interactive" value="interactive">Interactive Methods &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="discussion" name="discussion" value="discussion">Discussion &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="role" name="role" value="role">Role Play &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" id="quiz" name="quiz" value="quiz">Quiz
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the validation code is

```
if ((document.form1.lectures.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.study.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.audvid.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.interactive.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.discussion.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.role.checked == false)
      && (document.form1.quiz.checked == false)) { 

    alert("Please check any one method"); 
    isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
```

How do i insert only the checked values into mysql database, **implode** doesn't seem to help

**Edit :** If i use the same "name" for all checkbox implode works but in that case I'm not able to validate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697329/get-number-of-checkboxes-that-are-checked-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same name for all your checkboxes. You said `implode`, so that's good. As for the validation, change it to use the IDs:

```
else if ((document.getElementById("lectures").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("study").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("audvid").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("interactive").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("discussion").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("role").checked == false)
      && (document.getElementById("quiz").checked == false)) { 

    alert("Please check any one method"); 
    isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are only put in POST, if selected (checked).

PHP:

```
$keys = explode(',','lectures,study,audvid'); //get all keys
$result = array();

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key]) { //selected!
    $result[] = $key;
  }
}

print_r($result); //only selected checkeboxes are in result.
```